# How to set background color only for div in column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set background color only for DIV in column, but I getting background on full column. How do this?
Here is my code (very simple)

```
.news {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 20px;

    .news-thumb {
        img {
            border-bottom: 5px solid $Brown;
        }
    }
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <!-- DRUGI NEWS -->
    <div class="news">
        <div class="news-thumb">
            <img src="images/NewsThumb.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div><!-- /.news-thumb -->
        <div class="news-excerpt">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam,
                eaque!
            </p>
        </div><!-- /.news-excerpt -->
    </div><!-- /.news -->
</div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```

**UPDATE**
Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ufhwrg8w/)
  I have background on full width, but I want only for 'my-div'

[image]

Comment: Did you forget a `.row` container? Please demo the issue.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: No I have 'row' normally

Comment: I understand your issue now after your update, please check my answer again

Answer (score 1):

Use `div` in a another `div` this may help for you

See [Working demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/w3sgod1d/)

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap `.col-lg` is applied on width more than `1200px` so you will not see its effect on small screens like

[image]

but when I enralged the viewport to more than `1200px` it's look like

[image]

so all you need is to test on larger screen or to use `.col-md-4` or `.col-sm-4`

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard understand what you want...
Try this css:

```
/**
 * this select every DIV that match "col" in the class
 */

div[class*=col] {
  background-color: red
}




.news {
   background-color:green;
    padding: 15px 20px;

    .news-thumb {
        img {
            border-bottom: 5px solid yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added link in post

Comment: @Vertisan i see, but i don't understand: basically you have "my-div" in full width so the background-color cover the full area. Maybe you need to resize the div? Seriously man, i don't understand. Actually the demo you provided is right and works :-/

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ufhwrg8w/1/

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a smaller column size since the the column is only sized 4 for large screens, it'll default to taking up the full with for screens less than the width of a large screen (defined by bootstrap css)

so if you use `<div class="col-xs-4">`, it should work as you want it to.

https://jsfiddle.net/ufhwrg8w/3/ (updated js fiddle)

if you want the red to "hug" the img and not fill the full col-4, then use `display: inline-block` css on your div like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ufhwrg8w/4/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to play around with Bootstraps nesting columns. Something like this should help:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="news row"> <!-- Add row class here -->
            <div class="news-thumb col-xs-4"> <!-- Add new col class here -->
                <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/300/300" alt="placeholder image" class="img-responsive" />-->
            </div>
            <div class="news-excerpt col-xs-8"> <!-- Add new col class here -->
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam,
                    eaque!
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> <!-- Other column -->
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div> <!-- Other column -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.news {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.news-thumb {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Essentially you need to add another row inside your `.col-` element and within there create another set of columns. I've gone with 4 / 8 but these can be changed to whatever works best for you.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/bhxwof9h/

Bootstrap nesting: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting